# Ingest more than 30k users details from Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am facing an issue with iterating over 39k azure ad users in Azure Active directory.

I am able to get the ad users from Microsoft Graph API page by page.

As the Graph API provides results page by page, our scaling is limited to the number of records in a single page.

Thus, it takes a long time (more than an hour) to process the data for more than 10k users.

I want to know, if there is any other way I can use to get all the users in pages in parallel and process those batches of data in parallel.

Comment: Have you tried to use powershell `Get-AzureADUser -Top 10`(you could set the total number in one page).

Comment: You could try setting the page size bigger. Over an hour sounds like too much time for only 39k users.